# App crashing due to setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId())

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I am working on custom list view using arrayadapter,The app crashes with the following log

```
04-14 02:11:20.231 1584-1584/com.urjapawar.project E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.urjapawar.project.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:46)
```

and at **line 46** I have

```
holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
```

Here is the code of my **CustomAdapter.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem>  {
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                             List<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDesc;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());


    return convertView;
}
}
```

Here is **RowItem.java**

```
public class RowItem {
private int imageId;
private String title;
private String desc;

public RowItem(int imageId, String title, String desc) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
}
public int getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}
public void setImageId(int imageId) {
    this.imageId = imageId;
}
public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}
public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return title + "\n" + desc;
}
}
```

Here is **list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:paddingBottom="10sp"
    android:textColor="#CC0033"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:paddingLeft="10sp"
    android:paddingRight="10sp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
    android:paddingStart="10sp"
    android:paddingEnd="10sp"
    android:textColor="#3399FF"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener {
public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "H C Verma",
        "P Bahadur", "I E Irodov", "M L Khanna",
        "O P Tondon", "Morrison & Boyd", "Halliday Resnick",
        "R D Sharma", "S L Loney", "Hall and Knight", "Krotov", "I A Maron" };

public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {

        "Good For clearing concepts of physics",
        "Variety of examples on particular concept",
        "Read to become expert in physics",
        "Read to become an expert in mathematics",
        "A good reference for detailed stuff",
        "Read to become an expert in chemistry",
        "Interesting and fundamental book of physics",
        "Mandatory book forJEE aspirants",
        "Another good book for high rankers",
        "Simple and clear concepts of chemistry",
        "favourite one for physics lovers",
        "Read this for practice purposes"

};

public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.hcv,
        R.drawable.bahadur, R.drawable.irodov, R.drawable.mlkhanna,
        R.drawable.tondon, R.drawable.boyd, R.drawable.resnick, R.drawable.sharma,
        R.drawable.loney, R.drawable.knight, R.drawable.krotov, R.drawable.maron};

ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    rowItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

and one more thing, when I have copied the code and added necessary files in drawable folder from http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/ 
The code was working fine! All I have done is changed the name of objects and increased their number.

Comment: Try to print the value of rowItem.getImageId() and check if its null or not

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Seems No mistakes ...Code is running fine..

Comment: rowItem.getImageId is not null @Rakshit Nawani,

Comment: 04-14 02:11:20.231 1584-1584/com.urjapawar.project E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.urjapawar.project.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:46) is the exception @Dario

Comment: Hey Urja , I just created an app and copied your code..It is working fine..

Comment: @Urja, what you posted is location in code where exception occured, not exception itself... What i would like to know is which exception occured?

Comment: ok sir, I should probably go with base adapter, don't know why my app is getting crashed @ss_

Comment: Exception occurred at  holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId()); in customAdapter @Dario

Comment: You can use ArrayAdapter<RowItem> .

Comment: Is that Working ??

Comment: No sir, I have used ArrayAdapter still not working

Comment: Can u share ur mailID, I ll foward u that app

Comment: ok sir, sure ..urjapawar@gmail.com, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing troubling me was the size of the images I was using, we should use small size images otherwise it says something like

```
bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Thank you everyone for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `getItem()` on your CustomAdapter and return the data requested based on the `position` parameter

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more, what i have to inside getItem(int position)? and where is the function getItem tobe called?

Comment: I did what You said, It is still crashing

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ArrayAdapter use BaseAdapter instead.

Here is sample code

```
public class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private List<Data> dataList;
private Context context;

public SampleAdapter(Context context, List<Data> dataList) {
    this.context=context;
    this.dataList=dataList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return dataList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dataList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

class ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvDate;
    private TextView tvMobile;
    private TextView tvWifi;
    private TextView tvTotal;
    private ImageView imageView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        holder.tvMobile = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMobile);
        holder.tvWifi = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvWifi);
        holder.tvTotal = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
        holder.imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvDate.setText(dataList.get(position).getDate());
    holder.tvMobile.setText(dataList.get(position).getMobileData());
    holder.tvWifi.setText(dataList.get(position).getWifiData());
    holder.tvTotal.setText(dataList.get(position).getTotalData());
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);


    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: Ok sir, I will use base adapter

Answer (score 0):

I fix it! Now, I will working!!!

```
public class CustomAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private int[] mImage;
private Context mContext;
private ImageView mImageView;
private String[] mStringTitle;
private String[] mStringDesc;
private TextView mTextTitle;
private TextView mTextDesc;

public CustomAdapter(Context mContext, int[] image, String[] title, String[] desc, PageClickListener callback ) {
    this. mImage = image;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mStringTitle = title;
    this.mStringDesc = desc;
    mCallback = callback;

}

 public interface PageClickListener {
    void onPageClick(int id);
}

 private PageClickListener mCallback;


 @Override
public int getCount() {
    return mImage.length;
}

 @Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
 }

 @Override
 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, container, false);
    assert view != null;
    mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    mTextTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    mTextDesc = (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

    mImageView.setImageResource(image[position]);
    mTextTitle.setText(mStringTitle[position]);
    mTextDesc.setText(mStringDesc[position]);
    container.addView(view, 0);

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mCallback.onPageClick(position);
        }
    });
    return view;
}



@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}
}
```

in MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GuideAdapter.PageClickListener{
 public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "H C Verma",
    "P Bahadur", "I E Irodov", "M L Khanna",
    "O P Tondon", "Morrison & Boyd", "Halliday Resnick",
    "R D Sharma", "S L Loney", "Hall and Knight", "Krotov", "I A Maron" };

 public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {

    "Good For clearing concepts of physics",
    "Variety of examples on particular concept",
    "Read to become expert in physics",
    "Read to become an expert in mathematics",
    "A good reference for detailed stuff",
    "Read to become an expert in chemistry",
    "Interesting and fundamental book of physics",
    "Mandatory book forJEE aspirants",
    "Another good book for high rankers",
    "Simple and clear concepts of chemistry",
    "favourite one for physics lovers",
    "Read this for practice purposes"

 };

 public static final int[] images = new int[] { R.drawable.hcv,
    R.drawable.bahadur, R.drawable.irodov, R.drawable.mlkhanna,
    R.drawable.tondon, R.drawable.boyd, R.drawable.resnick, R.drawable.sharma,
    R.drawable.loney, R.drawable.knight, R.drawable.krotov, R.drawable.maron};

 ListView listView;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
 CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, images, titles, descriptions, this );
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }


@Override
public void onPageClick(int id) {

// enter code when onClick Item Here

}
}
```